# Binary wheel can't be uploaded on pypi using twine

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I am trying to upload a package on Pypi for linux and windows from github actions

with linux I get this result

```
Binary wheel 'xxx-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl' has an unsupported platform tag 'linux_x86_64'.
```

during windows installation

```
InvalidDistribution: Cannot find file (or expand pattern): 'dist/*'
```

the code for upload is that

```
  python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
  twine upload dist/* --verbose
```

Any ideas how to upload distributions for linux and windows?

Comment: You need to create a `manylinux1_x86_64` wheel. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46599004/7976758 for more references. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+has+an+unsupported+platform+tag+%27linux_x86_64%27

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot upload a `linux_*.whl` wheel to PyPI (reasons [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/#rationale)).

You'll need to convert this platform-specific wheel into a manylinux wheel via the [`manylinux` project](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) and the [`auditwheel` tool](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel).