# Create binary python package that depends on system-wide installed libssl.so

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, python-wheel

I am trying to create a binary python package that can be installed without compilation. The python package consists only one extension module written in C using the Python API. The extension module depending on the [stable python ABI](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html) by using `Py_LIMITED_API` with `0x03060000` (3.6). Up to my knowledge, this means the extension module can work for all CPython versions that are not older than 3.6. I managed to create the `sdist` package, and I explored `dumb`, `egg` and `wheel` formats. I managed to create the binary packages, but none of them is perfect for my use case.

The problem is the extension module is depending on `libssl.so`, and this is the only "external" dependency of it. Because the python package itself is very stable, it doesn't require frequent releases.  Therefore I wouldn't like to include `libssl.so` and take the burden of releasing new versions because of the security updates of OpenSSL (not mentioning to educate the users to update their python package regularly). I think because of this, the `wheel` format is not suitable, because the [`linux_*.whl` packages cannot be uploaded to PyPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451069/binary-wheel-cant-be-uploaded-on-pypi-using-twine/59586096#59586096), but the [`manylinux2014_*.whl`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0599/#the-manylinux2014-policy) tag has to include libssl.so (and its dependencies) in the package. The `dumb` package are not suitable for PyPI based distribution, the `egg` format is not supported by pip, so they are also not suitable.

Because of the stable ABI and the widespread of libssl.so, I think it should be possible to release a single binary package for the most linux distributions and multiple python versions (similarly to the `manylinux` tags with wheel). Of course the pacakge would require libssl to be installed on the machine, but that is something I can accept for achieving better security. And that's where I am stuck.

My question is how can I create a binary python package, which

1. contains a python extension module,
2. depends on the system-wide installed `libssl.so`,
3. and can uploaded to and installed via pip and PyPI?

I tried to explore other possibilities, but I couldn't find anything else, so if you have any tips for other formats to look after, I would appreciate that also.